# Getting error in Swiper Slider when using it with Next.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

Showing this error when i am using Swiper Slider with Typescript in a Next.js project. Here i want to link two swipers in the Swiper Slider library. I have created this project in Next.js with TypeScript. But i am getting this error , but this error don't arises in my React Project and only showing now when using in a TypeScript

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(swiper: Swiper) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'swiper' are incompatible.
    Type 'Swiper' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
      Type 'Swiper' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.ts(2322)
swiper-react.d.ts(36, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onSwiper' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, "onProgress" | ... 8 more ... | "onResize"> & SwiperOptions & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```

and here is the code that i directly copied from a demo of their website --

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/thumbs";

import { FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs } from "swiper/modules";

export default function App() {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        loop={true}
        spaceBetween={10}
        navigation={true}
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper2"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        loop={true}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={4}
        freeMode={true}
        watchSlidesProgress={true}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am showing you the part where the error is being displayed, the error is being shown in the second swiper where the code is --

```
onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
```

It is showing error below onSwiper. Here i trying to link the below swiper to the above swiper so that the above swiper moves with the below swiper